# Does the Simba JDBC Driver request compression from Big Query?

Tags: jdbc, google-bigquery, simba

We are attempting to optimize extracts of data in Big Query to Tableau. Using the Simba JDBC driver, we are noticing that it appears to be pulling raw uncompressed data. Rather than leveraging the BQ side compression. Which takes a process that BQ could do in 20-30 seconds, and makes it into a 3-4 hour process that may even error our when the data set exceeds the BQ limit.